# Getting linux information without fork/exec, popen(), and system()

Tags: c++, linux, process, system

I want to know how to get the following linux system information from C++ without using fork/exec, popen(), and system() :

1. Get the command string (name) that started the process for a
   given process id.
2. Send a signal to a process
3. Catch and display all the signals my program receives
4. Get the process id(s) for any given process name

Any hints would be appreciated.

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Shouldn't that be four questions?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the info for 1) is contained in  /proc/PID/cmdline

If you want the current process you can use /proc/self/ - handy when you don't know pid. I don't know much about C++ but in C you can use open and read syscalls to do it, which avoids forking.

I think a lot of the other answers you can probably do by manipulating /proc entries as well. I beleive /proc/PID/status tells you about signals that have been caught blocked and ignored by the specified PID as well.

edit: Thinking a bit more for 4) you can recursively loop through the pid entries in /proc to look up your given process name - this is only way I can think of without forking (calling "ps" from within code as other suggested requires a fork/exec). Is there a particular reason you are avoiding fork?

Comment: for 1) what about the ones that have nothing inside /proc/PID/cmdline?
Can't I just open a file stream to read from cmdline and find what I need?

Answer (score 1):

1. main function of a process receives that bit
2. kill - i.e. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html
3. See 2
4. Tricky.Requires me thinking

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on the first one? What do you mean the main function of a process receives that bit? How do I access the main function of a process?

Comment: 1. He's not talking about argv. He wants to be able to retrieve the command line that started any process, given it's pid.

Answer (score 0):

1. From main, you may print argv[0]. But that won't help always as the starting program may get replaced by a new due to call to fork/exec.
2. You need to use kill command line program or kill system call
3. Check the man page for sigaction
4. I am assuming you are meaning executable name. You may do the below, may not work on all Unix systems, but should work on Linux.

   ps -ef   | grep " program-name"  | awk ' { print $2 } '

Comment: I need to get the information from a C or C++ program, not command line :(

Comment: Then you may need to scan the /proc directory from your program. The /proc/<pid>/cmdline  contains the program name.

Comment: I tried checking into cmdline manually with VIM and there is nothing in there... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What does this command show ?? " $ cat /proc/1/cmdline " ---- It should print something like "/sbin/init".